# Can I use httpx to wait for the page to load?

Tags: python, html, parsing, request, httpx

```
import httpx

r=httpx.get('url')
```

I will not receive all the code of the page. How can I make all the scripts on the page load?

Comment: Maybe it'll be easier to use something like Selenium. Requests or httpx can't execute javascript themselves, they just perform a request and return fetched response without any evaluation. JS is executed by your browser, when you visit the site through it, so easiest way is emulating browser behaviour with more complex instruments.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented this through selenium, but I am looking for a faster way.

Comment: Is the data for scripts located in the page itself or fetched from ajax? If first, it may be much simpler to take it from not formatted source (usually json), just find a script that contains it. Otherwise you can track the ajax request from browser and perform it with httpx or requests. You may need to determine its structure to perform multiple ajax requests for different page without loading that pages.